# How to get ajax response fron JSON for multiple data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
["06-Feb-2017","12-Feb-2017","5","45","40","Neha shishodia","USD","unit2","phase1","Change Request","Client Approval Awaited"]["07-Feb-2017","04-Feb-2017","6","54","48","Neha shishodia","USD","unit2","phase1","Change Request","Manager Approval Awaited"]
```

This is my AJAX response, as I used `echo json_encode($arr)` in my PHP file for AJAX response. But I do not know how to get JSON data from AJAX response.

Comment: as you've blemished your question with the jQuery tag ... have you considered `jQuery.ajax` perhaps? or even `jQuery.getJSON`

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax short-handler [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method for getting json object.

```
jQuery.getJSON('file.php',function(arr){
   // arr holds the array, do the rest here
})
```